# Screeplot in R with psych package

Tags: r, pca

I have computed a PCA with the principal function in the psych package in R. I would like to build a screeplot from the eigenvalues, but both scree(PCA) and screeplot(PCA) give me errors and no plot. Is there a function within this package that I'm not aware of (I have very, very little R experience)??

NOTE: I've been simply working in the command line.

Error for scree(PCA):

```
Error in if (nvar != dim(rx)[1]) { : argument is of length zero
```

Error for screeplot(PCA):

```
Error in plot.window(xlim, ylim, log = log, ...) : 
need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(w.l) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(w.r) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Comment: Did you come right with your screeplot issues @DJV? I see you mention you are working with the command line. Take a look at **RStudio** as an editor it might be more easy to use/update packages/see your variables and debug.

Answer (score 1):

Without data it is hard for us to check this. The error message looks like the data is empty.

Here are some tips for R beginners.

1. Try get help on scree function. Are you missing a parameter? Type in command line.
   `help(scree)`
2. Look at your variable PCA

   `head(PCA)` - shows first few rows of your data

   `str(PCA)` - shows structure of the variable. Is it what scree function is expecting?
3. Do you have missing values or text values in your data? The function may be thrown out by these. You can drop missing data - take a look at `complete.cases`.  `is.na()` is how you check for NA values (i.e. if I wanted to check for NAs in variable `mydata`, `sum(is.na(mydata))` would tell me how many I have. Drop those rows and see if that gets your scree function working okay.
4. Take a look at the vignette for the package: 
   https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/psych/vignettes/overview.pdf

Hope this gets you on track.

Comment: I looked at the guide for psych. It suggest also looking at the function `fa.parallel` "Among the many ways to choose the optimal number of factors is the scree test. A better function to show the scree as well as compare it to randomly parallel solutions is found found in fa.parallel"

Comment: @DJV - did you come right with your screeplot problems?

Answer (score 0):

Did you enter a correlation matrix as your input to the `scree( )` function?

Using my own data, I was able to generate a scree plot with the following two lines of code:

```
humor_cor <- cor(humor, use = "pairwise.complete.obs") 
scree(humor_cor, factors = FALSE)
```